# Dynamic routing file SF2

Tags: symfony, routes

I am currently stuck on the multi-site management in Symfony2.

I have a Symfony2 project that allows multiple sites. Everything works fine but I block on managing files "routing".

My /app/config/routing.yml file I wish I could load the correct file routing.yml compared to the domain name:

```
project_routing:
    resource: "%MY_DOMAIN%/routing.yml"
```

Unfortunately I can not put variable %my_domain% a file routing so I do not see how to fix this ...

The structure:

```
app/config/routing.yml is redirected to my %my_domain%
app/config/www.mywebsite.com/routing.yml
app/config/www.otherwebsite.com/routing.yml
```

Comment: Do you want save route in other place ? For example inside your bundle?

Comment: I just add the current structure in my first post

Comment: When editing a post always make changes so (future) visitors can read it as a single coherent whole. Putting `EDIT` (or `Update`, etc) never achieves that goal, it just looks like you tacked something on as an afterthought. If we really need to see what changed, we can you use the edit history. Thanks are not useful content either, leave that out.

Comment: And please read the tag descriptions. Tag [tag:yaml] has about as much relevance as tag [tag:ascii] or tag [tag:file] would have.

Comment: ok, no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

So 1) base locale you can specify in `app/parameters.yml` 
like this:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

where `locale: en` default locale.

2) In default `app/routing.yml` file you should specify link for routing in your bundle like this:

```
fob_rental:
    resource: "@fobRentalBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

3) In my `src/fob/RentalBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` route looks like:

```
fob_offer_new:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/offers/new
    defaults: { _controller: fobRentalBundle:Offer:new }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|spa
```

Comment: Not the local variable is not a concern, I mean the variable%MY_DOMAINE%
Which contains for example: www.mywebsite.fr